# Is there any unix command that does not make any system call while executing?

Tags: shell-script, command

I have been wondering if there is any **Unix command** that does not make any **system** **call**. 
For example if we take into instance **`ls`** it also uses a lot of system calls, like **`open`, `read`, `write`**. We use the *`strace`*  command to find those calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/bin/true` and `/bin/false` don't have to make any system calls other than the required `exit(2)`.  (GNU true and false are dynamically linked ELF executables, so of course you get the usual boiler-plate startup).

If you write a program in asm that tries to return from `_start`, or that just keeps executing, it will segfault when execution jumps to an unmapped page.  So you technically *can* avoid calling `exit()`, but it's not worth it.  :P

You may have read that the simplest implementation of `true(1)` is an empty file.  This only works if called from the shell.

```
touch true
chmod 755 true
./true
echo $?
 0
strace ./true
 write(2, "strace: exec: Exec format error\n", 32) = 32
 exit_group(1)
```

If you want to make your own minimal `true` implementation, then on amd64 you can do:

```
cat > exit64.s <<EOF
    .section .text
    .globl _start
    _start:
            xor %edi, %edi
            mov $231, %eax  #  exit(0)
            syscall

    #       movl $1,%eax    # 32bit int80 can call the 32bit ABI system calls from long mode
    #       int $0x80
EOF

as exit64.s -o exit64.o && ld exit64.o -o exit64
strace ./exit64 
 execve("./exit64", ["./exit64"], [/* 69 vars */]) = 0
 exit_group(0)                           = ?
 +++ exited with 0 +++
file exit64
 exit64: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
```

Unlike GNU `true`, this one doesn't support `--help` and `--version`!  (e.g. `command true --version` to skip the shell-builtin.)

See also [A Whirlwind Tutorial on Creating Really Teensy ELF Executables for Linux](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) if you thought this was neat.

Comment: while using "strace true" it has system calls open(), close(), read() so my doubt still exists.

Comment: @DeepakSingh: read more carefully.  GNU /bin/true *could* be just `exit(0)`, but it isn't, because it's a dynamically linked ELF executable.  If you want to write a program that just exits without doing anything else, you need to avoid the libc startup.  Look at the strace output for the asm version of `exit64` in my post.

Comment: You could also write `_start()` in C, and compile with `-static -nostartfiles`.  I tried that with a call to `exit(42)`, but it segfaults, so I guess the glibc wrapper for the `exit` system call depends on something that the standard startup code does.

Comment: Update, I should have [used `_exit(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html) (i.e. the exit_group system call) which doesn't flush stdio buffers.  `exit(3)` (the ISO C standard function) faults when trying to access stdio data structures which are uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You could always write such a command, but it would take no input and produce no output.  Even `sleep(1)` has to use system calls to detect the passage of time.

**Edit**: a pure assembly program that does nothing but try to write forbidden memory, thereby terminating with `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: So it seems there is no possible command that does not make any system call.

Comment: Even `main(){}` relies on system calls to allocate memory (`sbrk(2)`) and run other startup code.  Plus, ending the program requires `exit(2)` :) .

Comment: `sleep(1)` doesn't get the time.  It sleeps using `nanosleep(2)`. :P